# Securing Process inside Docker Instance

Tags: linux, docker, process

While implementing an online C++ compiler, I'm running a Node.js server inside docker instance, which in turns create new process to execute the online code.

Need your help to secure the instance with the following:

(a) How to limit the CPU usage for the  newly created process?
(b) How to limit RAM and storage for this process?
(c) How to prevent the system from Fork Bomb?
(c) Limiting the time of the process run?

Though I can set these parameters using ulimit.conf, but it will apply the limits on per user basis. My requirement is to limit the resources per process basis because all the processes are running with the same user.

Kindly give a clue to handle the situation.

Thank you very much in advance for this support.

Comment: Is this a homework question, or is there an underlying problem you're trying to solve? These are covered by the docs already.

Comment: Hi BMitch, its not a homework question, its real problem. Kindly let me know how to handle the resources at process level. Its easy to manage it at user level, but I could not see any documentation which talks about process level resource management. For example, I want my process should not take more than 2MB RAM, should not create more than 10 files, should not have more than 100 child processes. Hope you understood the requirement now?